# Given a merged array, split it into individual arrays using JS

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript array like

```
[{"Employees":[{"id":1,"name":"Michale Sharma","gender":"Male","age":25,"salary":10000},{"id":2,"name":"Sunil Das","gender":"Male","age":24,"salary":5000},{"id":3,"name":"Robin Pandey","gender":"Male","age":35,"salary":45000},{"id":4,"name":"Mona Singh","gender":"Female","age":27,"salary":12000}],"Departments":[{"Deptid":1,"Deptname":"IT"},{"Deptid":2,"Deptname":"HR"},{"Deptid":3,"Deptname":"HW"},{"Deptid":4,"Deptname":"SW"}]}]
```

I want to split it like (for Employees)

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Michale Sharma","gender":"Male","age":25,"salary":10000},{"id":2,"name":"Sunil Das","gender":"Male","age":24,"salary":5000},{"id":3,"name":"Robin Pandey","gender":"Male","age":35,"salary":45000},{"id":4,"name":"Mona Singh","gender":"Female","age":27,"salary":12000}]
```

AND (for Departments)

```
[{"Deptid":1,"Deptname":"IT"},{"Deptid":2,"Deptname":"HR"},{"Deptid":3,"Deptname":"HW"},{"Deptid":4,"Deptname":"SW"}]
```

I have refereed [Split array into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks), but that's not the case.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to do it like that :

```
var obj = [{"Employees":[{"id":1,"name":"Michale Sharma","gender":"Male","age":25,"salary":10000},{"id":2,"name":"Sunil Das","gender":"Male","age":24,"salary":5000},{"id":3,"name":"Robin Pandey","gender":"Male","age":35,"salary":45000},{"id":4,"name":"Mona Singh","gender":"Female","age":27,"salary":12000}],"Departments":[{"Deptid":1,"Deptname":"IT"},{"Deptid":2,"Deptname":"HR"},{"Deptid":3,"Deptname":"HW"},{"Deptid":4,"Deptname":"SW"}]}]

var employees = obj[0].Employees
console.log(employees)
var dept = obj[0].Departments
console.log(dept)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data[0].Employees
// employees

data[0].Departments
// departments
```

Your data is wrapped in a one-element array, which is being unwrapped by `[0]`. Then, each of your desired value is directly available on that object as an attribute.

Comment: Since 1 cannot accept 2, so i accepted @huggilou. And already u have so many points but he is a new comer. Hope you won't mind (: But I made a justice to both by upvoting.